# How do you calculate the time dilation between the front and back end of a space ship?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, observers

If 2 spaceships are travelling in the same direction with the same speed, one after the other. Do their clocks show different times to a stationary observer?

Answer (score 2):

Assume the clocks are synchronized in their own rest frame.

They tick at the same rate in the stationary observer's rest frame. But they are offset. The stationary observer's space time diagram shows the line of simultaneity in the rocket frame is tilted. The lead clock in the stationary frame is behind. It will reach the time the trailing clock now shows when the lead clock reaches the rocket frame line of simultaneity that passes through the trailing clock.

[image: Minkowski diagram]

Picture from [The Naked Scientists](https://www.thenakedscientists.com/forum/index.php?topic=77589.0)

Answer (score 0):

If they have the same and constant velocity, their clocks tick at the same rate.

But it is possible that they are accelerated, with different accelerations, and only for a moment have the same velocity to a given inertial frame. In this case their clocks tick at different rates. It is the case of Rindle observers.